# Memoir: Increase header height for title page

Tags: header-footer, margins, memoir, titles

I have to use a particular latex template. On the titlepage there is a logo in the header which is to high.

> Class memoir Warning: The material used in the headers is too large
>   (78.7743pt) for the given head height (14.5pt), it is recommended to
>   either increase the head height or redesign the header (in both cases
>   you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 114.

Now I guess I have to use `\setheadfoot{ headheight }{ footskip }` (memoir manual page 20). The title page has a `\newgeometry` statement, I tried to insert it before and after but either the header is higher than the page or `\textheight` is not changed so the footer is below the border of the page.

Where should I set `\setheadfoot{ headheight }{ footskip }`? Or is there another way?

Comment: I'd redesign the title page not using the header for placing material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing it with the geometry package.

`\newgeometry{left=3.4cm,right=2.4cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=4cm,head=79pt}`

`\restoregeometry`

I don't know if mixing memoir and geometry package is a good idea but it's already done in some places in the template.